# invoking only existing method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I have a ref that contains a method that turns window into full screen. However, this method name changes depending the browser:

```
  const setFullscreen = () => {
    if (!elRef.current) return;

    elRef.current
      .requestFullscreen() // webkitRequestFullScreen on Safari
      .then(() => {

        setIsFullscreen(document[getBrowserFullScreenElementProp()] != null);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setIsFullscreen(false);
      });
  };
```

As you can see, Safari uses `webkitRequestFullscreen`, so the above code doesn't work in Safari.

How can I make the code work keeping it `DRY`? Found something similar here ([link](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull)) but it won't help keeping it DRY.

I was thinking in something like:

```
const requestFullScreen = elRef.current.requestFullscreen || elRef.current.webkitRequestFullscreen;

requestFullScreen().then .... more
```

However this doesn't invoke the method in neither of the browsers.

Comment: @Jesse no it is not a boolean, code is perfectly fine Read the docs on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: Try `requestFullScreen.call(elRef.current).then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to the target before calling it:

```js
const requestFullScreen = (elRef.current.requestFullscreen || elRef.current.webkitRequestFullscreen).bind(elRef.current);

requestFullScreen().then .... more
```

You can also add the failsafe with `|| () => {}` at the end to not crash when both `requestFullscreen` and `webkitRequestFullscreen` do not exist:

```js
const requestFullScreen = (elRef.current.requestFullscreen || elRef.current.webkitRequestFullscreen || () => {}).bind(elRef.current);

requestFullScreen().then .... more
```

Comment: That `bind` was the key. Thank you!